# How to retrieve start date and end date with correct time for current week in C#?

Tags: c#, datetime

**Before marking this question as duplicate, please read further**. I know this question is asked many times, but I have an addition to the general form of asking and I haven't managed finding the correct answer with respect to my use case.

I have a couple of `DateTime`-objects for a random time between monday and friday (no saturdays or sundays (!)).

For example:

```
2017-11-06 11:30:00.0000000 // Monday 6th November 2017
2017-11-07 13:30:00.0000000 // Tuesday 7th November 2017
2017-11-08 13:00:00.0000000 // Wednesday 8th November 2017
2017-11-09 15:00:00.0000000 // Thursday 9th November 2017
2017-11-10 16:00:00.0000000 // Friday 10th November 2017
```

I'd like to achieve the `DateTime` of the monday and the friday of this week *at 23:59/00:00*.

### Question ##

So for all mentioned `DateTime`-objects above, I'd like to achieve the monday at starting time and the friday of :

```
2017-11-06 00:00:00.0000000 // Start: Monday 6th November 2017
2017-11-10 23:59:00.0000000 // Start: Friday 10th November 2017
```

What would be the most efficient way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private DateTime GetDay(DayOfWeek dayName, DateTime dt)
{
    if (dt.DayOfWeek == dayName)
            return dt;
        while (dt.DayOfWeek != dayName)
        {
            if (dayName == DayOfWeek.Monday)
                dt = dt.AddDays(-1);
            else
                dt = dt.AddDays(1);
        }
        return dt;
}
```

> GetDay(DayOfWeek.Monday, Convert.ToDateTime("2017-11-06
>   11:30:00.0000000"));

should get you Monday of that week.

> GetDay(DayOfWeek.Friday, Convert.ToDateTime("2017-11-06
>   11:30:00.0000000"));

should get Friday of that week.

Once you get the date of Monday and Friday, you can change the time part of the returned DateTime object appropriately.

Comment: Less code compared to the other answer, this helps ;)

Comment: `GetDay(DayOfWeek.Friday, Convert.ToDateTime("2017-11-06 11:30:00.0000000"))` returns the wrong date `11/3/17 12:00:00 AM` instead of 2017/11/10

Comment: Edited the answer

Comment: Thanks for editing. Marked as correct answer, upvoted.

Answer (score 0):

As **Dirk Schmidt** answered in:
[Get date of first and last day of the week knowing week number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19901666/get-date-of-first-and-last-day-of-week-knowing-week-number)

```
public static DateTime FirstDayOfWeek(DateTime date)
{
    DayOfWeek firstDayOfWeek= CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.FirstDayOfWeek;
    int offset = firstDayOfWeek - date.DayOfWeek;

    return date.AddDays(offset);
}

public static DateTime LastDayOfWeek(DateTime date)
{
    return FirstDayOfWeek(date).AddDays(4);
}
```

Comment: In cultures where the first day of the week is sunday, this will be wrong.

Comment: What is in **firstDayOfWeek** variable?