# Get Week Number from Given Date in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I have date like 08/31/2013 and i want in which week given date falls.So please help me how can i achieved it.For e.g give date falls in 5th week of August.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11155102/1460657  here is a answer

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
var currCulture = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;

var weekNo = currCulture.Calendar.GetWeekOfYear(
            new DateTime(2014, 28, 03), //Any date
            currCulture.DateTimeFormat.CalendarWeekRule,
            currCulture.DateTimeFormat.FirstDayOfWeek);
```

Answer (score 1):

Found this [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/487469/getplusweekplusnumberpluswithinplustheplusmonthplu). Check if helps.

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
int weekOfMonth = (dt.Day + ((int)dt.DayOfWeek)) / 7 + 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Today;
CultureInfo ci = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
int weekNum = ci.Calendar.GetWeekOfYear(dt, CalendarWeekRule.FirstFullWeek,   DayOfWeek.Monday);
weekNum = weekNum / 12;
string weekday = dt.DayOfWeek.ToString();
```

With this code you will be able to get week number and week day of any date.....