# How to get week of the month when selecting a date in datetimepicker?

Tags: c#, winforms, datetimepicker

I have a `datetimepicker` control in winform which I am creating in c#.

How would I get the week number of the month when I select a date in `datetimepicker` control in c#?

That means, If I select the date as `09/09/2014` then the result should be shown in next `textbox` control as 2nd week of the month in the winform.

Please help me out.

Comment: what do you mean by '*week number of the month*' exactly?

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11154673/get-the-correct-week-number-of-a-given-date

Comment: I have edited question ,,Will u please look over It @jbutler483

Comment: @ShivaDebrown I would be happy enough with Sepehr's answer (it should work for you)

Comment: Yes Sepher's answer is working... Thank u too @jbutler483

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a simpler way to do this :

```
 private void dateTimePicker1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   txtweek.Text=  (1+(dateTimePicker1.Value.Day / 7)).ToString("0");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var month = datetimepicker.Value.Month;
var weekNumberThisMonth = (datetimepicker.Value.Day + (7 - (int)datetimepicker.Value.DayOfWeek)) / 7;
```

Comment: can't test this at present, but if it's the 1st of the month - won't this give it as 'Week 0'?

Comment: I'm getting error at math.floor()  @seepher farshid

Comment: Not sure if that works now (again) - what happens if you pass in **10**? you'd get **10+(7-10)/7** == 10+(-3)/7 == 7/7 == 1 yet should be 2nd week?

Comment: No! datetimepicker.Value.DayOfWeek is a number from 0 to 6!

Comment: So for today, it's 10 + (7 - 3 (Wednesday)) / 7 which is 14 / 7 = 2!

Answer (score 0):

txtweek.Text=  (1+(dateTimePicker1.Value.Day / 7)).ToString("0");

This is my answer