# Previous non-empty value in a DateTime LINQ join

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to join two files, one at **daily** granularity and one at **weekly** granularity.

I currently have this:

```
var combinedTrends = from daily in _dailyDict
                     from weekly in _weeklyDict
                     where DateTime.Parse(daily.Key) >= DateTime.Parse(weekly.Key.Substring(0, 10)) && DateTime.Parse(daily.Key) <= DateTime.Parse(weekly.Key.Substring(13, 10))
                     select new GoogleTrends
                     {
                         Date = DateTime.Parse(daily.Key),
                         WeekStart = DateTime.Parse(weekly.Key.Substring(0, 10)),
                         WeekEnd = DateTime.Parse(weekly.Key.Substring(13, 10)),
                         DailyIndex = daily.Value,
                         WeeklyIndex = weekly.Value
                     };
```

**Problem:** I'm losing daily rows where the week does not exist in weekly file.

**Input:**

```
1/1/2014    91
1/2/2014    82
1/3/2014    89
1/4/2014    100
1/5/2014    87
1/6/2014    64
1/7/2014    64
1/8/2014    64
1/9/2014    67
etc....

2014-01-05 - 2014-01-11 37
2014-01-12 - 2014-01-18 34
2014-01-19 - 2014-01-25 34
etc.....
```

**Expected Output**

```
Date        WeekStart   WeekEnd     D   W
01-01-2014  (empty)     (empty)     91  (empty)
01-02-2014  (empty)     (empty)     82  (empty)
01-03-2014  (empty)     (empty)     89  (empty)
01-04-2014  (empty)     (empty)     100 (empty)
01-05-2014  01-05-2014  01-11-2014  87  37
01-06-2014  01-05-2014  01-11-2014  64  37
01-07-2014  01-05-2014  01-11-2014  64  37
01-08-2014  01-05-2014  01-11-2014  64  37
01-09-2014  01-05-2014  01-11-2014  67  37
etc....
```

Comment: Why don't you check it between two values? I.e. `dateTime > weekBegin && dateTime < weekEnd`

Comment: Please add more information to your question: `include just enough code to allow others to reproduce the problem.` http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask Also, please include *current programme input and output* and *expected output*.

Comment: @EBrown More info in edit.

Comment: You should use a `JOIN` in this case, which will allow you to select all `daily.Value` and the relevant `weekly` values. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311040.aspx You would want `LEFT OUTER JOIN`. Also, can you provide definitions for the `_dailyDict` and `_weeklyDict` variables? I may be able to come up with something for you.

Comment: @EBrown Both are Dictionary<string, int>.  In _dailyDict, string is then parsed to DateTime.  In _weeklyDict, string has to be split to parse WeekStart and WeekEnd.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, so this wasn't as easy as a simple `JOIN`, and could surely be made faster, but here's the solution I came up with:

### Solution 1:

```
Calendar cal = DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.Calendar;

var combinedTrends = from daily in _dailyDict
                        join weeklySub in _weeklyDict on cal.GetWeekOfYear(DateTime.Parse(daily.Key), CalendarWeekRule.FirstDay, DayOfWeek.Sunday) equals cal.GetWeekOfYear(DateTime.Parse(weeklySub.Key.Substring(0, 10)), CalendarWeekRule.FirstDay, DayOfWeek.Sunday) into weeklyGroup
                        from weekly in weeklyGroup.DefaultIfEmpty(new KeyValuePair<string, int>(DateTime.Parse(daily.Key).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + " - " + DateTime.Parse(daily.Key).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"), 0))
                        select new GoogleTrends
                        {
                            Date = DateTime.Parse(daily.Key),
                            WeekStart = DateTime.Parse(weekly.Key.Substring(0, 10)),
                            WeekEnd = DateTime.Parse(weekly.Key.Substring(13, 10)),
                            DailyIndex = daily.Value,
                            WeeklyIndex = weekly.Value
                        };
```

Essentially, we take your original query, and add the following to it:

```
join weeklySub in _weeklyDict on cal.GetWeekOfYear(DateTime.Parse(daily.Key), CalendarWeekRule.FirstDay, DayOfWeek.Sunday) equals cal.GetWeekOfYear(DateTime.Parse(weeklySub.Key.Substring(0, 10)), CalendarWeekRule.FirstDay, DayOfWeek.Sunday) into weeklyGroup
from weekly in weeklyGroup.DefaultIfEmpty(new KeyValuePair<string, int>(DateTime.Parse(daily.Key).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + " - " + DateTime.Parse(daily.Key).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"), 0))
```

What this does, is tells LINQ to check that the week number of the `daily` item matches the week number of the `weekly` item, and if so return it. Otherwise it returns the same date as the daily record as the start and end of the week, with a `0` value.

### Solution 2:

Now, we could add helper methods which would get the first and last day of the week, to send a right-proper string to the `weekly` item with, and modify the query for it:

```
// We use this function because .NET does not implicitly consider the first and last weeks of the year the same.
public static int GetWeekOfYear(int weekNumber)
{
    if (weekNumber > 52)
        return 1;

    return weekNumber;
}

// This will get the week-range in a string of format "yyyy-MM-dd - yyyy-MM-dd".
public static string GetWeekRange(DateTime date, DayOfWeek firstDayOfWeek)
{
    int numberOfDayOfWeek = DayOfWeekToNumber(date.DayOfWeek, firstDayOfWeek);

    return date.AddDays(0 - numberOfDayOfWeek).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + " - " + date.AddDays(6 - numberOfDayOfWeek).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
}

// This converts the DayOfWeek to a number to allow us to easily determine how many days to add/subtract for the first/last days of the week.
public static int DayOfWeekToNumber(DayOfWeek dayOfWeek, DayOfWeek firstDayOfWeek)
{
    int[] r = new int[2];
    r[0] = 0;
    r[1] = 0;

    r[0] = DayOfWeekValue(firstDayOfWeek);
    r[1] = DayOfWeekValue(dayOfWeek);

    int result = r[1] - r[0];
    if (result < 0)
        result += 7;

    return result;
}

// This converts the DayOfWeek enum into a numerical value, Sunday being 0 and up from there.
public static int DayOfWeekValue(DayOfWeek dayOfWeek)
{
    switch (dayOfWeek)
    {
        case DayOfWeek.Sunday:
            return 0;
        case DayOfWeek.Monday:
            return 1;
        case DayOfWeek.Tuesday:
            return 2;
        case DayOfWeek.Wednesday:
            return 3;
        case DayOfWeek.Thursday:
            return 4;
        case DayOfWeek.Friday:
            return 5;
        case DayOfWeek.Saturday:
            return 6;
    }

    return -1;
}
```

Then we complete our Query:

```
Calendar cal = DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.Calendar;

DayOfWeek firstDayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Sunday;
var combinedTrends = from daily in _dailyDict
                        join weeklySub in _weeklyDict on GetWeekOfYear(cal.GetWeekOfYear(DateTime.Parse(daily.Key), CalendarWeekRule.FirstDay, firstDayOfWeek)) equals GetWeekOfYear(cal.GetWeekOfYear(DateTime.Parse(weeklySub.Key.Substring(0, 10)), CalendarWeekRule.FirstDay, firstDayOfWeek)) into weeklyGroup
                        from weekly in weeklyGroup.DefaultIfEmpty(new KeyValuePair<string, int>(GetWeekRange(DateTime.Parse(daily.Key), firstDayOfWeek), 0))
                        select new GoogleTrends
                        {
                            Date = DateTime.Parse(daily.Key),
                            WeekStart = DateTime.Parse(weekly.Key.Substring(0, 10)),
                            WeekEnd = DateTime.Parse(weekly.Key.Substring(13, 10)),
                            DailyIndex = daily.Value,
                            WeeklyIndex = weekly.Value
                        };
```

Personally, it is up to you as which method you should take, I think that the latter I mentioned would probably be best.

The output, of this solution by the way, is:

```
Date       WeekStart  WeekEnd    D   W
01-01-2014 12-29-2013 01-04-2014 91  0
01-02-2014 12-29-2013 01-04-2014 82  0
01-03-2014 12-29-2013 01-04-2014 89  0
01-04-2014 12-29-2013 01-04-2014 100 0
01-05-2014 01-05-2014 01-11-2014 87  37
01-06-2014 01-05-2014 01-11-2014 64  37
01-07-2014 01-05-2014 01-11-2014 64  37
01-08-2014 01-05-2014 01-11-2014 64  37
01-09-2014 01-05-2014 01-11-2014 67  37
```

Note: As indicated in the comments, the `GetWeekOfYear(int)` function exists because .NET will start a partial week as the first (`1`) week of the year, but will not end a partial week as the first, but instead as week `53`. This function returns `1` in that case, to allow for the two partial weeks to be joined properly.

Also, this was actually a fun problem to solve.

### Test Environment:

The following code and comments were used as indicated to test these solutions:

```
Dictionary<string, int> _dailyDict = new Dictionary<string, int>();

_dailyDict.Add("12/31/2013", 91);
_dailyDict.Add("1/1/2014", 91);
_dailyDict.Add("1/2/2014", 82);
_dailyDict.Add("1/3/2014", 89);
_dailyDict.Add("1/4/2014", 100);
_dailyDict.Add("1/5/2014", 87);
_dailyDict.Add("1/6/2014", 64);
_dailyDict.Add("1/7/2014", 64);
_dailyDict.Add("1/8/2014", 64);
_dailyDict.Add("1/9/2014", 67);

Dictionary<string, int> _weeklyDict = new Dictionary<string, int>();

// This line was removed and added to ensure that weeks that didn't exist would still return daily's.
//_weeklyDict.Add("2013-12-29 - 2014-01-04", 1);
_weeklyDict.Add("2014-01-05 - 2014-01-11", 37);
_weeklyDict.Add("2014-01-12 - 2014-01-18", 34);
_weeklyDict.Add("2014-01-19 - 2014-01-25", 34);
```

The following code was used to generate output:

```
foreach (var trend in combinedTrends)
{
    Console.WriteLine(trend.Date.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy") + "\t" + trend.WeekStart.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy") + "\t" + trend.WeekEnd.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy") + "\t" + trend.DailyIndex.ToString() + "\t" + trend.WeeklyIndex.ToString());
}
```

### References:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311040.aspx

[Get the correct week number of a given date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11154673/get-the-correct-week-number-of-a-given-date)

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.calendar.getweekofyear.aspx

Answer (score -2):

Try using a join

```
var combinedTrends = from daily in _dailyDict
                                 join weekly in _weeklyDict
                                 on DateTime.Parse(daily.Key) equals DateTime.Parse(weekly.Key.Substring(0, 10))
                                 select new GoogleTrends
                                 {
                                     Date = DateTime.Parse(daily.Key),
                                     WeekStart = DateTime.Parse(weekly.Key.Substring(0, 10)),
                                     WeekEnd = DateTime.Parse(weekly.Key.Substring(13, 10)),
                                     DailyIndex = daily.Value,
                                     WeeklyIndex = weekly.Value
                                 };
```

Comment: This won't work, as this checks that the daily date is the same as the weekly date. When the weekly date will be a range.

Comment: Still use the Join, just fix the date range so its the same as the original where.