# Calculate the week number from a date to another

Tags: c#, date, dayofweek

I have to calculate the week number based on a date. This might be easy and I've done in this way (thanks to another [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11154673/get-the-correct-week-number-of-a-given-date) post):

```
public static int GetCurrentWeekNumber(DateTime time)
{
    DayOfWeek day = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.Calendar.GetDayOfWeek(time);
    if (day >= DayOfWeek.Monday && day <= DayOfWeek.Wednesday)
    {
        time = time.AddDays(3);
    }
    return CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.Calendar.GetWeekOfYear(time, CalendarWeekRule.FirstFourDayWeek, DayOfWeek.Monday);
}
```

The new request is to calculate the week number not from Monday but from thursday to the next wednesday (included). Any hints?

Comment: Please link to that other SO post.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get the correct week number of a given date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11154673/get-the-correct-week-number-of-a-given-date)

Comment: From tuesday to the next wednesday, sure? That's a 8 day week.

Comment: Sorry, it was a typo, the correct range is from the current thursday to the next wednesday

Answer (score 2):

```
CultureInfo.DateTimeFormat.FirstDayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Tuesday;
```

Edit: (thanks to comment)

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.cultureinfo(v=vs.110).aspx

```
CultureInfo co = new new CultureInfo("en-US", true);
co.DateTimeFormat.FirstDayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Tuesday;
```

Comment: You will get an `InvalidOperationException` at runtime because the instance is readonly if you don't clone it.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Point taken, so let's clone it :)

Comment: It does also not take this into account: _"calculate the week number from tuesday to the next wednesday (included)"_ Although that would be a 8 day week. I'm not sure if OP really wants it.

Comment: Correct, it was a typo, I meant thursday

Comment: @TimSchmelter also something to consider, but there is no official way to give a weeknumber for a range exceeding the 7 days. As a week is always 7 days. But I'll give it a mathematical approach. (edit never mind after Ras's comment). For people who are curious: I wanted to write a modulo (%) 8 function that takes the first day of the year in consideration.

Comment: @user2754599: the method OP uses won't work immediately by changing the `DateTimeFormat.FirstDayOfWeek` to the desired day. Also, if you want to change the `FirstDayOfWeek` of the `InvariantCulture` this constructor doesn't help. You could use `Clone`: `var culture = (CultureInfo)CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.Clone();
            culture.DateTimeFormat.FirstDayOfWeek = weekStart;`