# What is the use of CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.Calendar.GetDayOfWeek?

Tags: c#, datetime, cultureinfo, dayofweek

I was checking out the week numbering codes and I have encountered with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11155102/1519458) on SO. I did not get the use of `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.Calendar.GetDayOfWeek`. Is there any reason for not using `DayOfWeek` property of `DateTime` as `time.DayOfWeek`. Am I missing something?

Related code block from the answer mentioned above:

```
DayOfWeek day = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.Calendar.GetDayOfWeek(time);
```

Comment: IMHO Invariant culture is culture independent and time might be culture dependent. So in this code it extracts culture independent day of week from culture dependant DateTime..

Comment: Is DayOfWeek effected by culture for a given date?

Comment: There is effectively no difference for the invariant culture (or indeed any other culture, as far as I can tell). So there isn't much use for this. I looked at all the implementations on ReferenceSource, and they appear to all be the same.

Comment: Well DateTime itself is not culture dependant, [it is dependant](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sk65c9c1(v=vs.110).aspx) on [Calendar](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.calendar(v=vs.110).aspx).    `ChineseLunisolarCalendar` and `GeorgianCalendar` on same date might have different day of week.

Comment: It could be affect the DateTime at time you get it from input or print it as timestamp string. Say, if you input datetime by year number. You might got difference DateTime in difference machine with diffrence culture thus it could affect the day of week you expect