# Get week ID from DatePicker using C#

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-5

Following code for getting weekid

```
 CultureInfo ciCurr = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
  int Weekid = ciCurr.Calendar.GetWeekOfYear(dt, CalendarWeekRule.FirstFourDayWeek, DayOfWeek.Monday);
```

> When I try for date 31/12/2018  it showed me **week Id 53**  but
>   in my DatePicker it showed **week Id 1**

Refer image of DatePicker

[image]

**Question:**

*which one is correct?*

*how to make it same either change in C# code or jquery code ?*

Comment: Both are correct, notice the `CalendarWeekRule.FirstFourDayWeek` parameter in C# that specifies HOW to determine first week of the year. As of what is jQuery using and how to change it - I don't know.

Comment: *CalendarWeekRule* I tried to change in rules but output provide me same. any other way

Comment: @Pravin what jQuery is doing appears to be `CalendarWeekRule.FirstDay`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code..

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11154921/1997983

```
 var d = new DateTime(2018, 12, 31);
            CultureInfo cul = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;

            var firstDayWeek = cul.Calendar.GetWeekOfYear(
                d,
                CalendarWeekRule.FirstDay,
                DayOfWeek.Monday);

            int weekNum = cul.Calendar.GetWeekOfYear(
                d,
                CalendarWeekRule.FirstDay,
                DayOfWeek.Monday);

            int year = weekNum == 52 && d.Month == 1 ? d.Year - 1 : d.Year;
            Console.WriteLine("Year: {0} Week: {1}", year, weekNum);
```

It is returning 1 for week 53 as per ISO-8601

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnste/archive/2006/01/24/iso-8601-week-of-year-format-in-microsoft-net.aspx

If you check the week of 31 Dec 2018, it will start from 30 Dec which falls on Saturday. From this year-2018 it will contain only two dates.. 30 and 31. Rest all 5 dates are from next year i.e. 2019. Hence it is returning 1 as  the week number which is correct as per ISO-8601 standard.