# PowerShell returns 2 as week number on January 06 2020

Tags: powershell, week-number, getdate

A quick question, apparently today (January 06, 2020) week number should be 2, because there are 53 weeks in 2020.

However, the following PowerShell snippet returns 1:

```
(Get-Date -UFormat %V)
```

What is the good approach getting the week number properly?

Comment: PowerShell defers to .NET for this, and .NET does not quite implement the ISO week number, as per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11154673/get-the-correct-week-number-of-a-given-date). The code snippets that fix this could be imported directly into PowerShell with `Add-Type`, or else the code is fairly easily converted directly to PowerShell.

Comment: Incidentally, the total number of weeks in the year is not relevant. The reason the (ISO) week number is 2 is because the previous week was 1, and the reason that week was 1 is because it's the week containing the first Thursday. This year has 53 ISO weeks because it's a leap year starting on Wednesday, but that's not an equivalent property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To translate this [Get the correct week number of a given date](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11155102/1701026) **C#** answer from [@il_guru](https://stackoverflow.com/users/454824/il-guru) into **PowerShell**:

```
Function GetIso8601WeekOfYear([DateTime]$Date) {
    $Day = (Get-Culture).Calendar.GetDayOfWeek($Date)
    if ($Day -ge [DayOfWeek]::Monday -and $Day -le [DayOfWeek]::Wednesday) {$Date = $Date.AddDays(3)}
    (Get-Culture).Calendar.GetWeekOfYear($Date, 'FirstFourDayWeek', 'Monday')
}
GetIso8601WeekOfYear (Get-Date)
2
GetIso8601WeekOfYear (Get-Date('2016-01-01'))
53
```

Answer (score 1):

You could detect a leap year and then adjust the week number based off the result.

```
if(((Get-Date).year)%4 -eq 0){
    $week = (Get-Date -UFormat %V) -as [int]
    $week++
}else{
    $week = (Get-Date -UFormat %V)
}
Write-Host $week
```

Comment: It seems it is not only sufficient to calculate the modulus by 4, other conditions also should be considered like this: 
`
$currentYear = (Get-Date -f yyyy)


if (    ( ($currentYear % 4 -eq 0) -and ($currentYear % 100 -ne 0) ) -or ($currentYear % 400 -eq 0)    ) 
{
    Write-Host "Leap"
} else {
    Write-Host "No Leap"
}`

Comment: I agree with @Abdul Rahman Sherzad, you can't just look to a leap year and add a week as that would e.g.  return **`54`** for **`1 jan 2016`**.