# Get count of weeks in given year for ISO 8601

Tags: c#, .net, date, iso8601

I am looking to get count of weeks in current year for `ISO 8601`. I was reading it also depends on location and calendar. I am intrested for `ISO8601`. I couldn't found any solution. The similar thing i found was `il_guru`'s which counts week number based on date. How could i nevertheless get count of s weeks for `ISO8601`?

This is `@il_guru`'s code below:
[Source link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11154673/get-the-correct-week-number-of-a-given-date)

```
// This presumes that weeks start with Monday.
// Week 1 is the 1st week of the year with a Thursday in it.
public static int GetIso8601WeekOfYear(DateTime time)
{
    // Seriously cheat.  If its Monday, Tuesday or Wednesday, then it'll 
    // be the same week# as whatever Thursday, Friday or Saturday are,
    // and we always get those right
    DayOfWeek day = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.Calendar.GetDayOfWeek(time);
    if (day >= DayOfWeek.Monday && day <= DayOfWeek.Wednesday)
    {
        time = time.AddDays(3);
    }

    // Return the week of our adjusted day
}
```

Comment: I suggest using [Noda Time](https://nodatime.org/3.0.x/userguide/weekyears) instead of trying to implement this yourself, specifically _WeekYearRules.Iso, which implements the rule specified in ISO-8601_

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date may help you: you have 4 different way to calculate it (all are equivalent, just one may be better for you, depending on how you have the dates)