# DateTime: Custom format specifier

Tags: c#, datetime

I'm not sure in which version of C# they got added, but you can now use format specifiers to format `DateTime` objects like this:

```
var date = new DateTime(2021, 01, 01);
System.Console.WriteLine($"{date:MM.dd}"); // 01.01
```

Now I want to get the calendar week from a `DateTime` object. Since ISO8601 specifies a slightly different week numbering than `.Net` uses it, I need to provide custom logic to get the calendar week. The Problem I have now is not how to get the correct week numbers, since Microsoft provided a solution to that in their blog and there's also the `ISOWeek` class, but rather: How I can add a custom format specifier like above so that I can do something like this?

```
var date = new DateTime(2021, 01, 01);
System.Console.WriteLine($"{date:WWW}"); // 53-2020
```

Is this even possible in C# 9? I'm guessing not since I've found very little on the topic so far.

Comment: Why not use an extension method? It's not as clean, but if custom format specifiers could be defined, that would lead to versioning problems.

Comment: If you use at least .NET Core 3, then you can use [ISOWeek](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.isoweek). Otherwise, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11154673/5114784) post (duplicate?).

Comment: @GyörgyKőszeg this is not a duplicate, since my question is not how to get the right week number, but rather how I can implement a custom format specifier

Comment: @AluanHaddad Yes that would be an option, and that's my current approach, but I just wanted to know if custom format specifiers are possible

Comment: @MrCodingB: Since you cannot derive the `DateTime` struct you cannot add new format specifiers to it. But nothing stops you to create a `CustomDateTime` type (maybe with an implicit operator for `DateTime` conversion) so you can implement the [`IFormattable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iformattable) interface with any custom logic. See the link for an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement custom format specifiers with the letters and tokens you want for new types that you implement.

But you cannot change the acceptable format tokens for built-in types, like `DateTime`.

Take a look at [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings).

Please note that what Microsoft calls *Custom Format Specifiers*, in this context, means combining the acceptable format tokens for `DateTime` as you wish, together with CultureInfo stuff.

You can check in the [reference source](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/DateTime.cs) how `DateTime` uses internally the class `DateTimeFormat`, that has a fixed set of tokens it accepts.

You best approach, I believe, is to write a method that gets the string and substitutes `"WW"` by `ISOWeek.GetWeekOfYear(date)`

Other options are:

- Write an extension method for your convenience
- Create a custom type implementing `IFormattable` with conversions to DateTime, overload operators and stuff... so much trouble, not worth it.

---

By the way, Custom DateTime Format Specifiers were introduced in c#6.

Comment: Ok, thanks! I suppose that would really be too much effort compared to a simple extension method. But thank you very much for the explanation.