# How to Find the Current Week Number in the Year, with Monday being the Start of a new week?

Tags: vb.net

Is there a way to find the current week number we are in out of the current year, where Monday is the start of the new week and not Sunday?

What I have so far:

```
Date_Time_Info = DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo
Calendar = Date_Time_Info.Calendar
Calendar.GetWeekOfYear(DateTime.Now, Date_Time_Info.CalendarWeekRule, Date_Time_Info.FirstDayOfWeek)
```

Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried till now?

Comment: @MaciejLos just edited the question with what i have

Comment: Question for you.  What constitutes week 1?  The First Monday or the January 1st?  For example if the first Monday is the 3rd of January, is that week 1 or is that week 2?

Comment: @GSerg, yes that does thank you

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11154673/get-the-correct-week-number-of-a-given-date This is the post that answered my question